# How to configure a gateway between a VPN and a local network?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, nas

In my application, I have a local network connected to the internet through a basic router.

- 192.168.0.0/24

  - basic router with DHCP (192.168.1.1)

    - Internet connection
  - IoT devices
  - Synology NAS (192.168.1.20)

    - VPN client to cloud VM (10.8.0.9)

From this network, we have a VPN connection to a VM which performs data aggregation.

We can currently SSH to the NAS from the VM, however, it is not yet possible to access the devices on the local network.

The goal is not to modify any parameters from the router.

I guess I need to configure a route/gateway on the NAS to access its local network.

Here my routes on the NAS:

```
$ ip route
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ovs_eth3  src 192.168.1.20
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
10.8.0.9 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.10
```

What would be the starting point?

Comment: Make sure the remote setup for the VPN client see the whole remote subnet.  e.g.  192.168.2.0 Mask 255.255.255.0  .  See if that helps

Comment: I tried that, but I have the same problem between the two networks 192.168.0.0/24 and the 192.168.2.0/24. From the VM side (192.168.2.1) I cannot access for instance 192.168.0.1, but I can access the VPN client (NAS) to 192.168.2.6

Comment: Your two networks cannot be on the same subnet; they must have different subnets.  I should have noted that in my first comment. Your VM might be able to be on the same subnet as the host that has the VM (so Bridged network).

Comment: There's no such thing as "gateway" when it comes to L3 tunnel (as in, the `via` part in a directly involved route is bogus / optional / ignored, since there's no Ethernet layer / ARP involved). You will have specify what VPN (e.g. OpenVPN, wireguard...) you are using. For OpenVPN, check out how to configure `iroute` in a "ccd file". For Wireguard, just add `192.168.1.0/24` to `AllowedIPs=` of the peer section of the NAS in the conf used on the VM. (Note that in all cases you still need a *direct route* added for `192.168.1.0/24`.)

Comment: I assume `192.168.0.0/24` in your question is a typo (of `192.168.1.0/24`) btw. And what's the LAN IP subnet of the VM? What are the `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24` in your comment are about?